# Extracting elements without class or id using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML page with below data :

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;padding-right:8px;" valign="top">
      <h2 class="sectionTitle">Corporate Headquarters</h2>
      <div itemprop="workLocation">6901 Professional Parkway East<br />Sarasota, Florida 34240<br /><br />United States<br /><br /></div><span class="detail">Phone</span>: <span itemprop="telephone">941-556-2601</span><br /><span class="detail">Fax</span>: <span itemprop="faxNumber">--</span>
      <h2 class="sectionTitle">Board Members Memberships</h2>
      <div>2011-Present</div><div><strong>Director</strong></div><div style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=11777224">TrustWave Holdings, Inc.</a></div><div>2018-Present</div><div><strong>President, CEO & Director</strong></div><div style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=22751">Roper Technologies, Inc.</a></div>
      <h2 class="sectionTitle">Education</h2>
      <div><strong>MBA</strong>  </div><div style="padding-bottom:15px;" itemprop="alumniOf">Harvard Business School</div><div><strong>Unknown/Other Education</strong>  </div><div style="padding-bottom:15px;" itemprop="alumniOf">Miami University</div><div><strong>Bachelor's Degree</strong>  </div><div style="padding-bottom:15px;" itemprop="alumniOf">Miami University</div>
      <h2 class="sectionTitle">Other Affiliations</h2>
      <div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=424885">MedAssets, Inc.</a></div><div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=1131022">Harvard Business School</a></div><div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=4109057">Miami University</a></div><div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=6296385">MedAssets Net Revenue Systems, LLC</a></div><div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=11777224">TrustWave Holdings, Inc.</a></div><div><a itemprop="affiliation" href="../../stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?capId=138296355">Medassets Services LLC</a></div>
    </td>
```

I'm trying to extract the information about "Board Members Memberships" as

```
Director 
TrustWave Holdings, Inc.


CEO & Director 
Roper Technologies, Inc.
```

These do not have any class or id for easy extraction.

But, All i'm able to do is :

```
soup.find('td',style="width:50%;padding-right:8px;").findAll("strong")
```

This gives me the following result :

```
[<strong>Director</strong>,
 <strong>President, CEO &amp; Director</strong>,
 <strong>MBA</strong>,
 <strong>Unknown/Other Education</strong>,
 <strong>Bachelor's Degree</strong>]
```

Can someone please guide me how to do it ?

Comment: Do you want the string "Director - TrustWave Holdings, Inc. CEO & Director - Roper Technologies, Inc."? It's unclear to me what it is exactly what you want.

Comment: @VincentBeltman I have edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: You used `td` tag within .find()` method but your pasted html elements don't contain that. Try sharing the link or including more elements to make it relevant to your try.

Comment: @SIM Please review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with navigation options provided in BeautifulSoup. A couple of loops and some conditional statements will help you to achieve what are you looking for.

Step 1: Iterate over all the `div` tags.

Step 2: Filter the positions by checking if the `div` contains `strong`.

Step 3: Navigate for the next `div` tag of the parent i.e. `div` with position.

Step 4: Filter the siblings with the condition that the company names are wrapped in `a` tag.

```
titles = soup.find_all('div')
for title in titles:
    if title.strong:
        company = title.find_next_sibling('div')
        if company.a:
            person_title = title.text
            person_company = company.text
            print(person_company, person_title)
```

Hope this helps! Cheeers!

Comment: This Worked :) Thank you.. :)

Comment: Happy scraping!

Answer (score 1):

My Python skills are a bit rusty, so I'll give you an answer in pseudo code to get you on your way. Good luck!!

```
result = ""

tdContent = soup.find('td',style="width:50%;padding-right:8px;")
headers = tdContent.findAll("h2")
for header in headers:
    if header.text == "Board Members Memberships":
        for (item = header; item.name != "h2"; item = item.nextSibling):
            if item.hasChild(strong):
                result += item.getChild(strong).getText + END_LINE
            if item.hasChild(a):
                result += item.getChild(a).getText + END_LINE
```