# Select all <table> elements without classes or ids with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I am trying to select all `<table>` elements on some web pages with BeautifulSoup. The table elements do not have specific classes or ids.

```py
import bs4
import requests

def get_keycode_soup(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")

def parse_qmk_soup():
    qmk_soup = get_keycode_soup("https://docs.qmk.fm/#/keycodes")
    tables = qmk_soup.select("table")
    # pass line for breakpoint
    pass

def main():
    parse_qmk_soup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have also tried selecting all the different table elements with

```py
tables = qmk_soup.find_all("table")
# and
table_rows = qmk_soup.find_all("tr")
```

Whenever I pause the debugger on the `pass` line, `tables` is always `None`.

I have tried some similar methods to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905578/extracting-elements-without-class-or-id-using-beautifulsoup) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523174/how-to-select-all-table-elements-inside-a-div-parent-node-with-beautifulsoup), but since there do not appear to be any other descriptive tags on the tables I'm trying to select, iterating feels inefficient.

Is there a way to simply select all the `<table>` elements on their own?

**Edit**: it appears that the page requires JS to load the tables as suggested by @DeepSpace below. Additionally, see the answer from @MendelG regarding following where the data is loaded from in case you might obtain the data from the source.

Comment: Try to print `res.text` and `ctrl + f` for the tables. If the page requires JS to load the tables they will be missing from `res.text` and BS won't be able to find them and you'll have to resort to headless scraping, ie selenium

Comment: I believe you are correct. They are not present if I view `res.text` - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect your browser's Network calls, and view the HTTP requests, you'll see that the data is loaded from a *different* website URL, which is:

```
https://docs.qmk.fm/keycodes.md?cache-bust=1706627991267
```

The thing is, it's really a markdown file (`.md`). However, at least you obtain the original file

So, there isn't really any HTML to parse, to obtain it in a readable format.

Comment: I appreciate this - pulling from the markdown file should enable me to accomplish my goal.